# designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport installation issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-9

Hello Devs hope you're doing well!

I'm trying to install designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport but this error keeps popping up:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport[v2.0.1].
    - designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport v2.0.1 requires illuminate/support ^5.5 || ^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

the commands I've executed prior reaching to this error:

```
curl -s "https://laravel-build/<name-of-project>" | bash

cd <name-of-project>

sail up

sail composer require illuminate/support "9.23.0"

sail composer require laravel/passport "10.4.1"

sail composer require mongodb/mongodb

sail composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

my version of php is **8.0** and laravel is **9.22**.

any idea how will I be able to install designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport? Thank you so much!

Comment: `designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport v2.0.1 requires illuminate/support ^5.5 || ^6.0` - anything unclear about that? The package you want to use is not compatible with Laravel v9

Comment: Yes, that part wasn't clear to me, unfortunately. I'll do more research on what version of Laravel is compatible with this package. Have you, by any chance, used designbynight/laravel-mongodb-passport as well?